# How to keep z-index in canvas when updating images via select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm building a poker table maker that works as follows:

1. When the page loads, I load the components of a poker table one-by-one.
2. Final users select what kind of felt, armrest, body or cup holders want on their poker tables through a select box.
3. When a change is detected in the select box, the src attribute of the Image object changes as well. For example: If a user wants a black felt, I'm loading the image: felts/black.png; then if he decides that it looks better in blue, the page loads the image felts/blue.png

My problem is the following:

As soon as they change one element of the poker table, the new image is automatically loaded on top of the rest .

For example:
If I change the felt color, the felt's image will go on top of the armrest's image.

I'd like to know how to force the felt image to maintain its z-index sort of thing.

Here's my code:

```
 var tableBody = new Image();
 tableBody.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(tableBody, 0, 0);
 };

 tableBody.src = "http://www.mcptables.com/images/buildyourtable/body/autumn-oak.png";

 /* and it does the same thing for the other parts of the poker table... tableArmrest, tableFelt
    tableCupholders, etc... */

 $('#armrest').change(
function() {
    switch( $(this).val() ) {
        case "black":
                tableArmrest.src = "http://www.mcptables.com/images/buildyourtable/armrest/black.png";
        break;
        case "brown":
                tableArmrest.src = "http://www.mcptables.com/images/buildyourtable/armrest/wood.png";
    }
}
)
```

You can see it in action on the following page:

http://mcptables.com/buildyourtable.html

And here's a link to my JS code:

http://mcptables.com/js/pokertablebuilder.js

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
If I want to change the

Comment: You could use an array to determine which image should be reloaded using a specific order (Body first, then Armrest ...). I don't think that there's anything like z-index in canvas

Comment: I'm note sure if I follow, could you elaborate a bit further, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to maintain the z-index of already drawn objects on a canvas. All you can do is delete everything and redraw appropriately.

There are canvas frameworks that take care of this and give the developer the "impression" of separate objects on the canvas. See processing.js, raphael, kineticjs etc

Comment: Bummer! I didn't know that. I'm going to check those frameworks out, but my guess is that for the scope of my tool, they might not be worth the hassle. Thanks a bunch!